# Python, Pandas : Return only those rows which have missing values

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

While working in Pandas in Python...

I'm working with a dataset that contains some missing values, and I'd like to return a dataframe which contains only those rows which have missing data.  Is there a nice way to do this?

(My current method to do this is an inefficient "look to see what index isn't in the dataframe without the missing values, then make a df out of those indices.")

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) `axis=1` to check for least one `True` per row, then filter with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: `df.isnull()` returns DataFrame after 0.23. Use `df.isnull().values.any(axis=1)` is a bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.isnull().any(axis = 1).sum()
```

this gives you the total number of rows with at least one missing data

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see only the rows that contains the NaN values you could do:

```
data_frame[data_frame.iloc[:, insert column number here]=='NaN']
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem I assume you want to view a section of data frame made up of rows with missing values I used

```py
df.loc[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use the code in this way

```
sum(df.isnull().any(axis=1))
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for a quicker way to find the total number of missing rows in the dataframe, you can use this:

sum(df.isnull().values.any(axis=1))